# How many nodes does Geth attempt to connect to by default?

Tags: go-ethereum, peers, node-discovery, discovery-protocol, p2p

Bitcoin Core tries to connect to 8 nodes by default. How many does Geth attempt to connect to for the `eth` protocol (normal network gossip)? Is there a set number in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geth attempts to connect to 25 peers by default, as stated on the [CLI commands page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options).

This can be changed with:

```
  --maxpeers value      Maximum number of network peers (network disabled if set to 0) (default: 25)
```